# Copying a stream in Python

Tags: python, io

How do I transfer the contents of a stream to another in Python?

The trivial solution would be

```
output.write(input.read())
```

but that fails if the input file is larger than the available memory (or even infinitely large); and it doesn't work well when a partial copy is useful as well. Basically I'm looking for the equivalent of [`org.apache.commons.IOUtils.copy`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`shutil.copyfile` and `shutil.copyfileobj` for the rescue. See http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#module-shutil

Comment: In particular, `shutil.copyfileobj`. I looked in shutil, but somehow didn't see it. Thanks!

Comment: sadly it can't copy paramiko's byte stream despite its having a file interface 