# Dump readable stream to a file

Tags: python, file-io, io, stream

I have a stream of data which I would like to write out to a file. My naive approach is to just loop reading chunks of data to the stream and write each chunk to the file:

```
with open(outputfile, "wb") as fp:
    while True:
        chunk = ostream.read(4096)
        if len(chunk) == 0:
            break
        fp.write(chunk)
```

I'm wondering if there is a built-in way to do this, or at least a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying a stream in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014520/copying-a-stream-in-python). You can treat the file as a stream - the same solutions apply